# Cannot execute system command in cygwin

Tags: perl, path, cygwin

I have the following simple perl script that I cannot execute in cygwin:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;


system("../cat.exe < a.txt > b.txt");
```

When I run it, the script tells me:

```
./my_test.pl
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However I can run the command in the cygwin shell:

```
$ ../cat.exe < a.txt > b.txt

$ ../cat.exe b.txt
hello
```

The executable cat.exe exists in the directory above and a.txt in the current working
directory.

My version of perl:
$ perl -v

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
(with 12 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer.  Was `/usr/bin/perl` actually a non-Cygwin perl executable?  If not, what was the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a perl built for Windows (ActiveState? Strawberry?), not the Cygwin version.  It invokes `cmd.exe` for `system()`, which thinks that `..` is the command and `/` introduces an option.

Try changing the the `system()` call to:

```
system("..\\cat.exe < a.txt > b.txt");
```

But you *should* normally be using the Cygwin version of perl when running a script from `bash`.

What is the output of the following commands?

```
echo "$PATH"
type -a perl
/usr/bin/perl -v
```

From what we've seen so far, it looks like you've installed some Windows-specific Perl with its `perl.exe` in your Cygwin `/usr/bin` directory.  If so, then (a) uninstall it (you can reinstall it elsewhere if you like), and (b) re-install the "perl" package via Cygwin's `setup.exe`.

(And add `use warnings;` after `use strict;` in your Perl scripts.  This isn't related to your problem, but it's good practice.)

Comment: @ikegami: I've rolled back your edit.  The evidence in the original question suggests that `/usr/bin/perl` *is* a non-Cygwin build.  Your edit shows `/usr/bin/perl` behaving correctly, which doesn't seem to be the OP's situtation.

Comment: No, he didn't show that he was using /usr/bin/perl. Anyway, the paths didn't matter. The example showed the different between the two Perls. I'll adjust to avoid the confusion

Comment: @ikegami: He ran `./my_test.pl`, presumably from a bash prompt (it would be a syntax error from `cmd.exe`.  The script starts with `#!/usr/bin/perl`.  If the command he showed us are the commands he actually executed, then `/usr/bin/perl` is *not* the Cygwin perl.

Comment: @Keith: I found the following: /usr/bin/perl was an ActiveState perl.

Comment: @Keith: Both /bin/perl and /usr/bin/perl were actualy ActiveState perls. Maybe my cygwin installation does not have a native perl. Is this something installed by defined. In any case `..\\cat.exe` solved my problem.

Comment: @user231536: That *works around* your problem; it doesn't solve it.  ActiveState's perl.exe isn't a Cygwin executable, and it shouldn't be installed under Cygwin's /usr/bin directory.  Cygwin doesn't install Perl by default; it's one of the (hundreds of) optional packages that you can install with [setup.exe](http://cygwin.com/setup.exe).  You have an inconsistent installation; you should fix it.

Comment: @Keith: Yes - the installation is definitely broken. I will fix it.

Comment: @ikegami: Based on the OP's recent comments, I've rolled back to my original answer.  His `/usr/bin/perl` really is the ActiveState perl.

Comment: Incidentally, `/usr/bin` `/bin` happen to be the same directory in Cygwin.  (This isn't particularly relevant to your problem.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Why did you remove the example that shows the problem is that he's running ActivePerl? Didn't he just admit that was the problem?

Comment: @ikegami: Yes -- and that's what I said in my original answer.  Your edit, at least your first one, assumed that /usr/bin/perl.exe was the Cygwin perl, and that he was running ActiveState Perl from elsewhere.  In fact, as I speculated, ActiveState Perl had been incorrectly installed as /usr/bin/perl.exe.  I felt that your edit didn't necessarily add useful information; I think I covered all the bases, even in hindsight, in my original answer.

Comment: None of my edits made any such assumptions. I actually ran the code and actually got the output. The code demonstrated how cygwin Perl and ActivePerl behave to backup your otherwise unsubstantiated explanation. Given the lack of substantiation, it feels like something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error message obviously comes from `cmd.exe`, which apparently is your default shell. What does `echo $SHELL` say? Maybe you need to define that variable to become `/bin/bash.exe`.

Comment: $ echo $SHELL gives me:
/bin/bash

Comment: The default shell shouldn't matter.  `system()` uses `/bin/sh` on Unix-like systems, including Cygwin, and `cmd.exe` for Windows systems.  It would be very bad for `system()` to behave differently for different users, depending on their default shells.

Comment: Perl doesn't use `$SEHLL`. It uses `cmd` on Windows, `/bin/sh` elsewhere including cygwin.